# Is there any way to read an webpage using c++

Tags: c++, html

I know that we can retrieve a webpage content through curl http://curl.haxx.se/ but is there any native way to retrieve the content of an webpage using c++ without using any library?

Comment: There surely is, but why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Yes, you just have to implement curl!

Answer (score 6):

You will always need some kind of library in order to establish a network connection (I count OS APIs as libraries). That aside, you would have to:

1. establish a connection to the server
2. send a http request
3. receive and handle the http response

You can implement these steps by hand, but that really is a pain, especially because [http is quite a complex protocol](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) (even if you only implement the stuff you actually use, enough remains).

Comment: +1: Wise answer. @sarvan: Even if you (re)implement HTTP yourself, it is very likely that you forgot to implement something important ("HTTP redirect" comes to my mind). Do yourself a favor, use an existing and known-working library like curl.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Windows, you can use functions below

InternetOpen() - Initializes an application's use of the WinINet functions.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385096(VS.85).aspx

InternetOpenUrl() - Opens a resource specified by a complete FTP, Gopher, or HTTP URL.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385098(VS.85).aspx

InternetReadFile() - Reads data from a handle opened by the InternetOpenUrl
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385103(VS.85).aspx

InternetCloseHandle() - Closes a single Internet handle
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384350(VS.85).aspx

Hope it helps

PS: or you can use a more convenient function

URLDownloadToFile() - Downloads bits from the Internet and saves them to a file.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775123(v=vs.85).aspx